# Can you solve any mathematical function?

Tags: functions, closed-form, inverse-function, elementary-functions

For any finite mathemathical function (consisting of addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, exponentiation, trigonometry) can you find $x$ in $f(x) = y$ where $y$ is a number you want?

Is it proven that any function is solvable or not solvable? Can a computer solve a function that's millions of characters long?

I tried to solve a large function in maxima but it got in an infinite loop.

Comment: More precisely, what you are actually asking is whether every *elementary function* has an *elementary inverse*. You may want to look into the concept of an elementary function in order to pose your question more accurately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)  need not have an elementary inverse. Consider

$$f(x)=xe^x,$$

whose inverse is the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications) function, which cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135911/how-to-prove-lamberts-w-function-is-not-elementary)).

Answer (score 2):

As Golden_Ratio noted, there isn't always a nice, closed form for the inverse of an elementary function. But a computer can get arbitrarily close to a solution to an elementary function, if it exists. Have a look at the Wikipedia page on [root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms).

Comment: You mean close to a *root*, but yes, good point. I would even go further: numerical methods are often more valuable, if a numerical value is ultimately desired. For instance, the exact expression for the root of a trinomial may be difficult to compute numerically (there are round-off problems with the straightforward formula).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean solving a function ($y$ is a variable), not solving a number equation ($y$ is a number). That are two different mathematical problems.

Your problem makes sense only if $x$ is a variable for elements of the domain of the function $f$ and $y$ is a variable for elements of the range of the function $f$. If $x$ is not a variable for elements of the domain of $f$ or $y$ is not a variable for elements of the range of $f$, the function is not solvable.

A function is a relation between two sets (domain and range) that assigns exactly one element of the range to each element of the domain. An [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) exists only for bijective functions, but the inverse relation always exists. Your question asks for determining the inverse relation of $f$. If you are looking for functions instead of a relation, you can subdivide the inverse relation into its branches (function branches), the [partial inverses (means partial inverse functions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) of $f$.

Because the inverse relation always exists, it can be calculated numerically.

You can also ask for partial inverses in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression).

If $f$ is a composition of functions $f_1,...,f_n$: $f(x)=f_n(f_{n-1}(...(f_2(f_1(x)))))$ and the partial inverses of $f_1,...,f_n$ are known/allowed, the partial inverses $f^{-1}$ of $f$ are: $f^{-1}(x)=f_1^{-1}(f_2^{-1}(...(f_{n-1}^{-1}(f_n^{-1}(x)))))$, where $f_i^{-1}$ is a partial inverse of $f_i$ ($i\in\{1,...,n\}$).

Let $A$ be an algebraic function and $f_1,...,f_n$ algebraically independent functions. You cannot solve $A(f_1(x),...,f_n(x))=y$ for $x$ if the domain of the function $A\circ f_1\circ ...\circ f_n$ is a non-discrete set and simultaneously only $A,f_1,...,f_n$ and their partial inverses are known/allowed.

$f$ is an explicit [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) in your example.

For elementary partial inverses of elementary functions, the algebraic independence is proved implicitly in the main theorem in [Ritt 1925] that is also proved in [Risch 1979]:
If $f$ and its inverse are both elementary, then $f(z)=\phi_n\circ\  ...\circ\ \phi_1(z)$, where each $\phi_i$ is either an algebraic function of $z$ or else $\exp$ or $\ln$.

See e.g. the function $f$ with $f(x)=xe^x$ from the other answer.
$\ $

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)

[[Risch 1979] Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373917?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)